# How can I search a column in MySQL containing unix timestamps with a query referencing a different format?

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp

I have a mysql table that contains something like:

```
+-------------+-----------------+
| FOO1        | FOOTIME         |
+-------------+-----------------+
|        blah |   1234567890000 |
+-------------+-----------------+
```

FOOTIME uses unix timestamp.

I want to run a query that essentially says "how many rows contain foo time older than January 1st 2012?

I thought I'd want to do something like `select count(*) from foodb.FOOTABLE where FOOTIME <= TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01');` but that didn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: The function you want is **[`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

SQL code:

```
SELECT COUNT(FOO1)
FROM footable
WHERE FOOTIME >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01');


SELECT COUNT(FOO1)
FROM footable
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(FOOTIME)>='2012-01-01';
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE footable (
  FOO1 varchar(30) primary key,
  FOOTIME int(11)
  );

INSERT INTO footable (FOO1, FOOTIME)
VALUES ('blah', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR)),
('Blahblah', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR)),
('BLablahblah', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 YEAR));
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77fc9/16)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to use `WHERE FOOTIME<UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-01-01')`? That way the conversion function is only called once (instead of being called for each row), and the query could use an index on FOOTIME if one exists.

Comment: @GordThompson I changed the answer. Your query was indeed more efficient. It saved 2 ms in this same example alone.